# Building Assimp with MinGW

Tags: makefile, cmake, mingw, mingw32, assimp

So, I am now for hours trying to build Assim with mingw. I reinstalled mingw and also redownloaded assimp, and I keep getting errors.

I begin with CMake choosing MinGW Makefiles for the generator of the project and Radio Box Use Default native compilers.
2) After that I get this error:

[image]

I manage to make this work by renaming the directory C:/MinGW/mingw32 to something else.

After changing names I start the process again:
The process does not give me any errors, so It seems to work fine. The thing is that it gives me this message in the configuring process:

```
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - not found
```

So I don't know if that is a problem or not. I ignore this and generate the files.

Now with windows Power Shell I enter the folder where the Makefile is located ....assimp-3.1.1/build, and I give the command:

```
mingw32-make
```

It starts now building, after a while it shows this error message:

[image]

I had assimp working with Visual Studio, but I had to change to another IDE, now I am completely lost.